# Does Swift Automatically Clone Arguments?

Tags: parameters, swift, arguments, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have been reading the iBook Apple released on Swift, and I am currently reading about functions. In this chapter they discuss the inout keyword. The led me to wonder: does swift automatically clone arguments when they are passed as parameters into functions? If not, could I create a constant equal to the variable I want to pass into the function and then pass it the constant to avoid mutating the variable if I do not want to? ex (By the way, I know that integers are immutable. I am just using integers to keep it simple.)

```
var variable: Int = 5
let constant = variable
let returnVale = function(constant)
```

(Sorry if this is an obvious answer. I have very little programming experience.) Thank you for any help.

Comment: As mentioned in the really good answer by nhgrif, the key concept here is "pass by reference" versus "pass by value" (your "clone"). Just knowing that those are the standard phrases should allow you to find a whole lot of information on the subject of your question in general, and in Swift.

Comment: I also edited the question tags to include the "pass-by-reference" and "pass-by-value" tag, so there's probably some good StackOverflow reading on the topic just by clicking on one of these tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, value type variables are passed to methods and functions not just by value, but as constants by value.

That is, not only can the function not change the value of the variable outside the function, it can't even change the value of the variable INSIDE the function.

In order for a function to modify the value inside the function, the function must declare the parameter as a `var` parameter.  Doing this allows the function to modify the variable inside the function, however this still does not effect the variable outside the function.

Only when `inout` is specified can a function modified the variable outside the function.  In this case, we've passed the variable by reference.

For more reading on this topic, [here's a link to the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).  If you scroll down about two-thirds of the way, you'll find a section called "Constant and Variable Parameters" and another section right after this called "In-Out Parameters".

---

You don't have to worry about knowing when a function will or won't modify your variable.  It's pretty easy to know.  When a function has declared a parameter as an `inout` parameter, you need to use the "address of" operator in the function call with that parameter.

This is the example function from the documentation:

```
func swapTwoInts(inout a: Int, inout b: Int) {
    let temporaryA = a
    a = b
    b = temporaryA
}
```

Now, given the following two Ints:

```
var someInt = 3
var anotherInt = 107
```

We can not call the above function as such:

```
swapTwoInts(someInt, anotherInt)
```

The compiler would complain:

> Passing value of type 'Int' to an inout parameter requires explicit '&'

To fix the compiler complaint, we must use the address-of operator:

```
swapTwoInts(&someInt, &anotherInt)
```

Now the compiler is happy, and that `&`, the address-of operator, serves to us as a big red flag that we've passed our variables by reference and the function could modify their values.

Comment: In the Swift language, the ampersand (`&`) placed before an argument for an `inout` parameter is not an "address-of operator". It's just an ampersand, which is required for syntax reasons. But of course, the generated code will in fact require the address of the provided argument.

Comment: If I am using a class, which are reference types, that I created, how can I clone them if I pass them as parameters?

Comment: If you want to pass a class by value, you most likely need to use a `struct`.  But for a class, you cannot pass it by value.  The best you can do is make a copy of the class and pass the copy in by reference.